# Using Typeahead Bloodhound inside a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scope, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have a basic jQuery plugin defined as such:

```
(function( $ ){
    var new_row_num = 0; 

    // Test data for now
    var courses = [
        {
            course_num: "M118",
            title: "Finite Math"
        },
        {
            course_num: "M119",
            title: "Calculus"
        }        
    ];

    // constructs the suggestion engine
    var courseSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('course_num'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local: courses
    });    

    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {

        },
        add : function( ) {
            // Adds a new row to my table
        }
    };

    $.fn.studentCourseBox = function(methodOrOptions) {
        if ( methods[methodOrOptions] ) {
            return methods[ methodOrOptions ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || ! methodOrOptions ) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.studentCourseBox' );
        }    
    };
})( jQuery );
```

The idea is that each time I add a new row using this plugin:

`$('#myWidget').studentCourseBox('add')`,

it will automatically initialize a Typeahead field in one of the columns.  Unfortunately, I get a Javascript error "ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined" at the first reference to Bloodhound.

However if I move the variable initializations for `courses` and `courseSuggestions` outside of the plugin, and pass them in via the `init` method, it works just fine.  So, I know that Bloodhound works in my script, it just doesn't work **inside my plugin**.

What am I doing wrong?  I feel like this is a scoping issue, but I've tried `$.Bloodhound`, `$.fn.Bloodhound`, etc and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I had my Javascript includes in the wrong order.  I had the JS resource for `Bloodhound` loaded *after* this code, so my browser must have been trying to instantiate `courseSuggestions` before `Bloodhound` was defined.  Not sure why it worked when instantiated outside of the plugin, though.